# How to delete a keyframe of an object at a specific frame with python?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes

Say I have an cube that has keyframes baked already. Using python scripting, is it possible to do something like object.delete_keyframe(frame=1), which deletes all keyframes of that object at frame 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object.keyframe_delete("location", frame=1)` will delete location keyframes at frame 1. But if you want to delete all keyframes you can do like this:

```
import bpy

def remove_keyframes(object, frame):
    action = object.animation_data.action
    if action is None:
        return
    for fc in action.fcurves:
        object.keyframe_delete(data_path=fc.data_path, frame=frame)
        
        
# testing:       
remove_keyframes(bpy.context.object, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Baking an animation causes all of the actions of that animation to be converted to a single action.  In the process of doing so it replaces every Nth step in the animation's in-between calculation with a new keyframe.  That effectively deletes the original F-Curve and replaces it with one that does not have the same keyframes.  So if you are asking if you could delete the original keyframe and effectively redo the bake, the answer is no.

On the other hand, if you're simply asking how to delete the keyframes at a specific frame number, the code below will do this for you.  Or you could use the dope sheet and do it manually.  But this won't be the same as deleting the original keyframe at that location.

This will work both for baked animations, and for animations that have not yet been baked.  The pass through NLA tracks is required for the later.

```py
def remove_keyframes(object, action, frame_number):
    for curve in action.fcurves:
        object.keyframe_delete(data_path=curve.data_path, frame=frame_number)

def delete_all_keyframes(object, frame_number):

    animation_data = object.animation_data

    if animation_data.action:
        remove_keyframes(object, animation_data.action, frame_number)

    for track in animation_data.nla_tracks:
        for strip in track.strips:
            remove_keyframes(object, strip.action, frame_number)
```

Here's a sample call, to delete all the keyframes on the current object at frame 10:

```py
delete_all_keyframes(bpy.context.active_object, 10)
```

Comment: Sir, if there are 30 frame & i want to delete last all 10 keyframe for some object how to use this code.